# mPDF not creating PDF from server

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mPDF to generate the pdf document from HTML and to save it. It's working fine on my localhost but when I use the same code on Server the pdf document is not creating and saving. I have full Access permissions to the Folder where I am saving it and the path is also right.

What might be the issue in generating the pdf document from the Git server? The code is as below:

```
include_once("pdf/mpdf.php");

        $mpdf=new mPDF( ); 

        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);

        $file_path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test\\';
        $mpdf->Output($file_path.$filename.'.pdf', 'F');

        //==============================================================
        $sql = "UPDATE master SET ratioid ='x' WHERE ID=".$row['ID'];
        mysql_query($sql);
```

It's setting the value of ratioid=x but the pdf document is not generating.

Is there anything to do with the Git server?

Comment: `$file_path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test\\';` can't work on remote server.

Comment: @panther: I tried this too $mpdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filename.'.pdf', 'F'); but it too didn't worked.

Comment: In `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` isn't the last slash, is it? Try to write `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filename.'.pdf'` if there is what you expected. Check the rights. mPDF should have any debug mode (https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/error-messages.html), try to check it.

Comment: @panther, based on your link I tried to debug the code but it says perfect. The values in the db are updating but the pdf documents are not generating.

Comment: can you upload it to server, add a debug mode and `print_r($mpdf);`after `->Output` (or before)? I can't help you more without an example, don't know mpdf well.